# How to find linearly independent linear combinations of a set of vectors (general case)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector

If I have a list of vectors, say $v=\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \dots ,v_{n}\}$.

Is there a way that I can get all linearly independent linear combinations of these vectors, such that if I change the content of the vectors or the number of vectors, it would still output all linearly independent linear combinations?

I can only do it manually with specific examples but I am sure there must be a general way of doing this, not dependent on one specific example.

An example would be:

$$G =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

where I want to get all linearly independent linear combinations of the rows of the matrix $G$. But would it be possible to do this in such a way that if I took a different matrix $G'$ with different rows, would it still work?

Comment: Please post a concrete example.

Comment: There are an infinity of linearly Independent linear  combinations. To get one of them that is orthonormal you may apply the Gram–Schmidt algorithm.

Comment: what if I restricted it to the binary case?

Comment: Could use `RowReduce` and discard any zero rows.